# SonarQube server is running but not reachable and saying 404 not found

Tags: vagrant, sonarqube, ubuntu-14.04, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-web

I am running windows 10 and installed virtual box to use ubuntu with the help of vagrant, so finally i have ubuntu 14.04 running with vagrant on windows

I have installed SonarQube by following [here](https://hostpresto.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-sonarqube-continuous-inspection-on-ubuntu-14-04/)

so sonar cube was installed in ubuntu at `/opt/sonar/bin/linux-x86-64/` and it is running good when i checked as below

```
(env) vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/Work/sonar$ sudo /opt/sonar/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh status
SonarQube is running (7705).
```

my sonar properties file(`/opt/sonar/conf/sonar.properties`) contains below settings

```
sonar.jdbc.username=sonar
sonar.jdbc.password=sonar
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
sonar.web.host=127.0.0.1
sonar.web.context=/sonar
sonar.web.port=9002
```

Now when i tried to access it as below it is saying `404 not found`

```
(env) vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/Work/sonar$ wget http://127.0.0.1:9002
--2017-07-31 08:07:32--  http://127.0.0.1:9002/sonar
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:9002... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-07-31 08:07:32 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

So can anyone please let me know what might be the reason that the sonar server is not accessible using the link `http://127.0.0.1:9002/sonar` and what changes needs to be done or am i missing something in `sonar.properties` file ?,

FYI, I am using `wget http://127.0.0.1:9002/sonar` instead of typing it browser url is, since because I am running ubuntu using vagrant inside windows i need to make port forwarding etc., which is additional work, and so just for the time being i accessed it like above

Comment: Are you sure the url is not simply `http://127.0.0.1:9002` (without sonar)? With Sonar 6.1, I access the dashboard with http://localhost:9000/dashboard/

Comment: @LoicM. Yes I am sure about it, that's what i mentioned in the `sonar.properties` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution i found to the above problem is just to comment the below options and restart the sonar server

```
#sonar.web.host=127.0.0.1
#sonar.web.context=/sonar
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're installing sonar on vagrant VM, you can do the following :

1. use a static IP for your VM, in your Vagrantfile add something like

   ```
   Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
     config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"
   end
   ```
2. you can reference this IP in your sonar properties file

   ```
   sonar.web.host=192.168.50.4
   ```
3. you will be able to access the server with this IP. (http://192.168.50.4:9002 in your case and `/sonar` or not depending if you use the `sonar.web.context` properties)

The other option would be to use the special address `0.0.0.0` so it is bound to all network interfaces. In this case you don't specifically need a static IP for the VM and you can use the `127.0.0.1` address using port forwarding.